# Why does a decorated function only return its value once all the decorated functions that are using that decorator are done?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Why does a decorated function only return its value once all the decorated functions that are using that decorator are done? In other words, why does the code below only print the value once both functions are done.

```
def decor(func):
    user_input = int(input())
    return func(user_input) * 3

@decor
def single(num):
    return num * 1

@decor
def double(num):
    return num * 2

print(single)
print(double)
```

Comment: Decorators are executed when they are _used_ (not when the function they decorate is called), so you execute the two `input()` statements even before your main program runs. A corollary to this is that it's not a good idea to ask for user input in a decorator.

Comment: When you using your ``@decor``, you actually do ``single = decor(single)``. ``double=decor(double)``. Btw, returning a value, not a func, is legal but not common in decorator.